# How control opened tab in my web browser application?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

Hi I'm new on C# and I made some simple Web Browser with tabs.

My problem is I don't know how to control selected tab. I mind if i click to back it go back on the selected tab.

Sorry for my bad English. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace HardRam
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int i = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }           
        private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
          webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }

        private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }
        private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        }
        private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }
        private void toolStripButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            webBrowser1.Stop();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?&q=" + textBox2.Text);
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        private void toolStripLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        private void toolStripButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage newTp = new TabPage();
            WebBrowser newWB = new WebBrowser();
            newWB.Name = "Page" + tabControl1.TabPages.Count + 1;
            newWB.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            newWB.Url = new Uri(@"http://www.google.com");
            newTp.Controls.Add(newWB);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTp);    
        }

        private void toolStripButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?&q=" + textBox2.Text );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `webBrowser1` will be an instance of a web browser, you probably have more than one

Answer (score 0):

You make an instance of `web-browser` for each tab,so you have to get current tab and its `web-browser` control , so in.see my following example:

```
private void btnaddtab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage newTp = new TabPage();
            WebBrowser newWB = new WebBrowser();
            newWB.Name = "Page" + tabControl1.TabPages.Count + 1;
            newWB.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            newWB.Url = new Uri(@"http://www.bing.com");
            newTp.Controls.Add(newWB);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTp);   
        }

        private void btnback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls[0] as WebBrowser).GoBack();
        }

        private void btnforward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls[0] as WebBrowser).GoForward();
        }
```